# Obtener id MYSQL con Ajax

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, ajax

Tengo un enlace que al darle click me lleva a receta nueva, pasándole la id del paciente

```
<a href="{{ route('receta-nueva', $paciente->id) }}" class="btn btn-success">Crear Receta</a>
```

La ruta es esta que me lleva al create del Controlador RecetaControler

```
Route::get('/recetas/nueva-receta', [App\Http\Controllers\RecetaController::class, 'create'])->name('receta-nueva')->middleware('can:super_admin_esp');
```

En el create me lleva a la vista receta.crear

```
public function create(Paciente $id)
    {
        
        return view('receta.crear');
    }
```

En esa vista hay un formulario y un botón

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('receta-crear')}}" style="margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 2em;" class="row g-4" id="formulario">

<button id="guardar" type="button" onClick="myFunction();" class="btn btn-primary"  >Generar Datos</button>
```

Cuando le das al botón te ejecuta codigo Ajax en el que te guarda los datos del input en mysql

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#guardar").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var url_base = jQuery("#url").val();

        jQuery
            .ajax({
                headers: {
                    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": jQuery('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
                },
                url: "/recetas/crear-receta",
                method: "post",
                data: {
                    unidades: jQuery("#unidades").val(),
                    producto: jQuery("#producto").val(),
                    info_farmaceutico: jQuery("#info_farmaceutico").val(),
                    instrucciones_paciente: jQuery("#instrucciones_paciente").val(),
                    diagnostico: jQuery("#diagnostico").val(),
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    jQuery.alert({
                        columnClass: "col-md-8 offset-m3",
                        title: "Mensaje",
                        content: "Ha ocurrido un error" + xhr.responseText,
                        type: "red"
                    });
                },
            })
            .done(function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    JQuery.ajax({
                        data:{
                            id: jQuery(this).val(),
                        }
                    })
                    window.location.replace(url_base + "/recetas");
                }, 1000);
            });
    });
});
```

En el controlador RecetaController tengo esto:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
        $receta=new Receta();

        $receta->unidades = $request->unidades;
        $receta->producto = $request->producto;
        $receta->info_farmaceutico = $request->info_farmaceutico;
        $receta->instrucciones_paciente = $request->instrucciones_paciente;
        $receta->diagnostico = $request->diagnostico;
        $receta->save();
        
        

        $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'La receta se ha guardado satisfactoriamente');

        return redirect()->route('recetas');
    }
```

La idea es que tengo que, después de guardar datos en mysql, me recoga la id que se ha generado para ponerlo en un div de esa misma vista(crear.blade.php). El id me lo genera de manera incremental en Mysql.
Gracias

Comment: Solo pon `$receta->id`

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado al momento?

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el id asignado al registro es con `$receta->id;`